# Python 2.7 and xbmc plugin

Tags: python, plugins, xbmc

I have the code below programmed with Python 2.7.10.

```
import re, urllib, urllib2

def penazadi():
    reqazadi = urllib2.Request('http://web.tv/embed/live/97294')
    reqazadi.add_header('Referer', 'http://tvizle.kurtcebilgi.com/azadi-tv')
    response = urllib2.urlopen(reqazadi)
    rdazadi = response.read(5900)
    rxazadi = re.compile('index.m3u8\?ttl=(.+?)"')
    wmazadi= re.findall(rxazadi,rdazadi)
    smazadi='index.m3u8?ttl='
    gmazadi=str.join(smazadi,wmazadi)
    restazadi='http://live1.cdn.web.tv/streams/415b828121291eb48f01cc26b98c14ff/'
    erazadi = ''.join([restazadi,smazadi,gmazadi])
    tx="'"
    frrazadi = ''.join([tx,erazadi,tx])
    return frrazadi

print penazadi()
```

Although I can not add it to this plugin (https://app.box.com/s/2pd6ugrdcgjpk8wx0s307sgpve7y39by) for Kodi.

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mind updating your question with the plugin name?

Comment: Thanks for the correction and the update

Comment: Anyone can help me with this?